# Python regexp \w

Tags: python, regex

The [Python manual](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/re.html) states:

> The special sequence \w for 8-bit (bytes) patterns matches characters 
>   considered alphanumeric in the ASCII character set; this is equivalent to 
>   [a-zA-Z0-9_].

Compare now:

```
re.search(r"([\w]+)", 'München').group(1)
```

with:

```
re.search(r"([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)", 'München').group(1)
```

The first statement outputs the whole city name München, the second only the first letter `M`. The letter `ü` is a single byte with code point `0xFC` = `252` (Latin-1). 
My question is: assuming that the Python manual is correct, how can I reconcile the difference in output between `[\w]+` and `[a-zA-Z0-9_]+`  with the statement in the Python-3 manual? I use IDLE v. 3.6.2.

Comment: `re.U` flag is enabled by default (=`\w` matches any  Unicode letters and digits) in Python 3. Python 3 strings are Unicode strings, not byte strings, by default.

Comment: But I use Latin-1, not UTF-8. And should the manual not mention the re.U flag?

Comment: What do you actually need? Make `\w` always match only `[A-Za-z0-9_]` in Python 3? Then pass `re.ASCII` flag.

Comment: @P.Wormer The manual _does_ mention that. You just didn't read the correct section. You aren't working with `bytes`, so why do you quote the `bytes` section?

Comment: I wrote a little  Python program that counts words in a text that is in Latin-1. The text  contains single byte characters between 128 and 255 (accented characters). To my surprise \w+ did exactly what I wanted (counted words with accented characters). Now I try to understand what is going on.

Comment: Maybe the reading of the file did a conversion from Latin-1 to UTF-8?

Comment: The manual doesn't mention re.U (the unicode flag) because Python 3 uses unicode strings by default. You have the re.ASCII flag to restrict patterns to ASCII type behaviour, which is also done if the pattern is a bytes object rather than str. You've read the `bytes` specific paragraph when your pattern is `str` (unicode).

Answer (score -1):

You referenced wrong manual (manual for python 3.1).

The correct one is at https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

If you want `\w` work like `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, you should use the flag `re.ASCII`:

```
>>> re.search(r"([\w]+)", 'München').group(1)
'München'
>>> re.search(r"([\w]+)", 'München', flags=re.ASCII).group(1)
'M'
>>> re.search(r"([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)", 'München').group(1)
'M'
```

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure what source you're quoting from, but your link says:

> For Unicode (str) patterns:
>
> Matches Unicode word characters; this includes most characters that can be part of a word in any language, as well as numbers and the underscore. If the ASCII flag is used, only [a-zA-Z0-9_] is matched (but the flag affects the entire regular expression, so in such cases using an explicit [a-zA-Z0-9_] may be a better choice).
>
> For 8-bit (bytes) patterns:
>
> Matches characters considered alphanumeric in the ASCII character set; this is equivalent to [a-zA-Z0-9_].

I'm still primarily using Python 2, but one of the big changes in Python 3 is that all strings are Unicode by default. Python will convert text to Unicode upon reading it.

Comment: I'm sure that the text I'm reading is in Latin-1. The text  is actually older than Unicode. Maybe Python converts it somewhere (upon reading maybe?).

Comment: OK that is the answer: Inadvertently I worked with UTF-8 and should have realized that the re.U flag is on. Thank you all!